# Phaser blocked status only works for static bodies?

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework

I have created a physics sprite in Phaser:

```
export class Player extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {...}
```

I am using the `blocked` status to see if my player sprite collides with any other physics object.

```
console.log(this.body.blocked)
```

This works for static physics bodies, the player is standing on the floor or on a platform:

> {none: false, up: false, down: true, left: false, right: false}

But when the player is colliding with another sprite, in this case a moving platform (which is a normal body, not a staticBody), then the `blocked` status is:

> {none: true, up: false, down: false, left: false, right: false}

Why is this? Does the `blocked` property only work for static bodies? And if so, how can I know if the player is standing on a non-static body?

Comment: The code from Phaser 3 source indicates that the `block` property gives this result by default and it means that it doesn't collide with a *tile or the world boundary*, so when it collides with another sprite i think it's not executed so it gives the default value wich is `{none: true, up: false, down: false, left: false, right: false}`